# How to create location blocks in nginx for a single file but have it follow the rules of another location block in addition to it's own?

Tags: nginx

I have a location block for / that does all of my fastcgi stuff and it has a normal timeout of 10s.  I want to be able to have different timesouts for certain files(/admin, sitemap.xml). Is there an easy way to do this without copying the entire location block for each location?

```
location /admin{
 fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
 #also use the location info below.
}

location /sitemap.xml{
 fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
 #also use the location info below.
}

location / {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8014;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
            fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR $http_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two possibilities, of which the second would be the most flexible.

### 1

You could try:

```
location /admin{
    fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
    include snippets/location.fcgi.conf;
}

location /sitemap.xml{
    fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
    include snippets/location.fcgi.conf;
}
```

File `snippets/location.fcgi.conf` (no need for location block there):

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8014;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
# ...
```

### 2

Or I guess you could go like this.

```
location / {
    # set you default, so we don't bomb out
    set $timeout 2s;
    # your other general stuff
}

location /sitemap.xml{
    set $timeout 5m;
    include snippets/location.fcgi.conf;
}

location /admin{
    fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
    include snippets/location.fcgi.conf;
}
```

**NOTE:** All include paths are *always* relative to the Nginx main config folder.
And yes, you can put them wherever you want provided that you have a symlink in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit between location blocks but what you can do is use the [include directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#include) to place all your common configuration directives in one file and then include that in each location.